# Toggling between astable and monostable input to dual 555 timer pulse generator

Tags: 555, battery-operated, toggle-switch, astable, monostable

[image: Circuit Diagram]
Hi there,

I am looking to build a simple analog circuit to generate adjustable pulses for a medical device. The current circuit utilises 2x LMC555 timers - one in an astable configuration to generate free-running adjustable trigger pulses for the second, which is in monostable configuration and from which the output will be sent to a small ERM vibration motor (such as that found here: https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/jinlong-machinery-electronics-inc/C1034B018F/1670-1009-ND/6009914). I require the ability to generate short pulses (of around 50ms), with an adjustable inter-pulse interval of around 3-5s.

I would like to be able to toggle between using the first astable timer as a trigger ("free-running mode"), and using a push button to manually trigger the motor output ("manual mode"). This toggle switch is shown above as S1. My question is this: Would the circuit design above be able to achieve this, particularly with regards to all components sharing the same power and ground lines? If not, would it be possible to use a more sophisticated switching set-up such that only one power source (in this case, a 9V battery) can be used to power the whole circuit?

I have previously tried to implement a much simpler version of this circuit using an Arduino microcontroller to adjust the output pulse length, amplitude and inter-pulse interval. However, the device is to be used in conjunction with EEG recordings, and I found that my Arduino-based implementation caused RF interference with the EEG measurements. For this reason, it is necessary to use a purely analog approach.

Comment: Battery + LM7805 + NE555 == Very short battery lifetime; I hope you're using a CMOS 555 variant?  Also, you should be putting the switch on the battery side of the regulator to not drain the battery when it's off. Also, 5V is too little for the NE555. Also, you're omitting **at least** 4 decoupling capacitors that you should really have. Is there a regulatory reason to use 555s? because this design looks crazy complex for such a simple task that would need about 2 components, 4 if you included power supply, if you didn't insist on the 555.

Comment: So, questions, please answer **all** (by editing your question): **1.** are you using a (classical) BJT 555 (like NE555) or a CMOS 555 (like LMC555)? **2.** What is the reason to choose a 555 to fulfill such an ostensibly state-machine-alike complex task? **3.** We'll need information on the small motor. Can it be switched low-side? Your "LED instead for simplicity" didn't simplify sensibly, sadly!

Comment: Hi Marcus - thank you for your reply! I have since edited the question and circuit diagram addressing (I believe!) the points you have raised. Please do let me know if I have misunderstood, happy to clarify further.